# Django+Angular 2 in one port

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am new in python and django. I want that my django project work with angular 2 in one port (for example localhost:8080). I visit many page, but I don't find project django that's work with angular 2 in one port. Please help me find simple project django that's work with angular 2 in one port.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two process listening in the same port. However you can have a load balancer linstening in one port and redirecting traffic based on url for example [Nginx](https://nginx.com).

Another approach is build Angular, and configure Django's urls to serve the outputed static files.